# How to use a array in a class which keeps it values and is acessable from outside the class

Tags: php, arrays

I am using php 7.4.9 and have a class which reads information from a file. These informations should be all the time availabe from outside the class and it also should possible to modify that array, so that this class can write back these information on request.
I have looked for a while but could not fined a useful solution.

I got the functions working, but the array loose the values from call to call.

**Edit 2020/12/12**

This is the uses structure of my code

```
<?php
.......

    function show(){
        $id3 = ID3::create();
        $mp3 = &ID3::$mp3Array;             
        if($mode == "manual"){
            if($file == ""){
                return "";
            }
            $fName = $dir . "/" . $file;
            $id3->open($fName);
            
        
.......
    }else if($mode == "save"){
        $fName = $dir . "/" . $file;
        $id3->save($fName);
        return "Save done!";

    }


    } // end of show

class ID3{
    
     public static $mp3Array = array();

    public static function create(): self {
    static $object;
    $object = $object ?? new self();
    return $object;
}   

 
 
    function open($fName){
    
    $mp3 = self::$mp3Array;
. // $mp3 will be filled

.........
    }
    
    function save($fName) {
        $mp3 = &ID3::§mp3Array;
        error_log("TagSave: ".var_export($mp3, true),0);  // is always empty

        foreach($mp3 as $key => $value){ 
            ........
        }
    }

    } //end of class>
?>
```

If I try to save the modified array, it is always empty, if show is called again!

I have also implemented the @Logifire proposal 'create'. I got a valid pointer but the arrayis still empty.
Maybe I should point out, that it is web page. The html code sends information (form) back to the php program.
I figured out, that use of global `$id3 = NULL;` does not work, because the php grogramm will be always called and set the variable again to NULL each time.

I have also implemented the following code on the beginning

```
<?php
error_log("PHP call",0);
$id3count = 0;
if(array_key_exists("Test_id3",$GLOBALS)){
    error_log("GLOBALS[Test_id3] exist!",0);
}else{
    error_log("GLOBALS[Test_id3] does not exist!",0);
    $GLOBALS['Test_id3'] = "NEW";
    }
```

The `$GLOBAL['Test_id3']` never exist, if the programm will be called!

Comment: If it's meant to accessible outside the class. You should have the function return the array to fill a global variable. With out code and data it's a guessing game.

Comment: You can put the array in a public property of the class. Or you can put it in a private property, and write methods that allow outside callers to read and write array elements.

Comment: @JasonK If a function returns an array, the caller gets a copy.

Comment: @Barmar I also don't have any reproducible code  to look at. That array is being saved to a file. Probably losing data due to multiple processes accessing it at once.

Comment: @HGA Show your code and we'll help you fix the problem that the array loses its values.

Comment: Most likely you're forgetting to use `$this->array_name`, and just using `$array_name`

Comment: Keep in mind that php is typically used in a multi process environment like a http server. That means multiple _independent_ processes would try to simultaneously access that file. Are you really sure you took care of that? How? TO me this reads like you want to use a database. That actually is what databases are for...

Answer (score 0):

> I got the functions working, but the array loose the values from call to call.

As I understand you, your setup is not a long running app, you can not keep state between requests (calls).

But if you are aware of that, the issue may be you have a new instance of the class each time you call it within the same request flow, you may use a singleton if this is the case. I suggest using accessors in your class.

```
class MyDataList {

    private array $my_array = [];
    
    private function __construct()
    {
        
    }
    
    public static function create(): self {
        static $object;
        $object = $object ?? new self();
        return $object;
    }
    
    public function setArray(array $new_array): void {
        $this->my_array = $new_array;
        // open, write, close file..
    }
    
    public function getArray(): array {
        return $this->my_array;
    }
}

$my_data_list = MyDataList::create();
```

Based on your edited question (2020/12/12), I extended the example code:

```
class MyDataList {

    private array $my_array = [];
    
    private $file_path = '';
    
    private function __construct()
    {
        
    }
    
    public static function create(string $file_path): self {
        static $object;

        if ($object === null) {
            $object = new self();
            $stringified = file_get_contents($file_path) ?: '';
            $array = json_decode($stringified, true) ?: [];
            
            $object->file_path = $file_path;
            $object->my_array = $array;
        }
        return $object;
    }
    
    public function setArray(array $new_array): void {
        $this->my_array = $new_array;
        $stringified = json_encode($new_array);
        file_put_contents($this->file_path, $stringified);
    }
    
    public function getArray(): array {
        return $this->my_array;
    }
}

$my_data_list = MyDataList::create('/path/to/file');
```

*Note: Be aware, you need to apply error handling*

---

Comment answers:

> Is the filepath connected to the array?

Well, you will write your data as JSON to a file each time you "modify" the array via the `setArray()`

> Does it means, that the array is stored into a file and read out each time I try to connect again?

For each request you call `create()` it will instantiate the internal state of the array based on the stored data in the file. ATM. The `file_get_contents` call may have been wrapped and only called if the `$object` was not instantiated. (**Now updated in the example**)

> So I have to call setArray($array); to save the data. I was looking for a soluting to keep the data without an management to save and read the array. Is this not possible with PHP?

Maybe you want to use a session variable to store your data? But it is individual per user and not long lived data - Link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
In a standard PHP setup you can not have data/state between requests, but there are solution like Swoole which makes PHP a long running app: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.swoole.php

> I need a possibility to modify the array directly.

Is it a reference to the array you want? https://3v4l.org/OsBC6

```
class MyDataList {

    private array $my_array = [];
    
    private function __construct()
    {
        
    }
    
    public static function create(): self {
        static $object;
        $object = $object ?? new self();
        return $object;
    }
    
    public function setArray(array &$new_array): void {
        $this->my_array = &$new_array;
    }
    
    public function getArray(): array {
        return $this->my_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have some problems to understand your code. I need a possibility to modify the array directly. Your first proposal was taking care, that I always get the same pointer to the class MyDatalist. The second proposal requires a file_path. Is the filepath connected to the array? Does it means, that the array is stored into a file and read out each time I try to connect again? So I have to call `setArray($array);` to save the data. I was looking for a soluting to keep the data without an management to save and read the array. Is this not possible with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do with PHP!
Finally I use the proposal from Logifire, but had to modified it to fullfill my requirements.

1. I needed more than 1 array.
2. One array can ibclude binary data values, which json can't handle. So I have to use base64 for the binary data values.

Here my code:

```
 public array $mp3Array = array();
     public array $findArray = array();
     private $file_dir = "";
    

    public static function create(string $fileDir): self {
        static $object;

        if ($object === null) {
            $object = new self();
            $stringified1 = file_get_contents($fileDir."/mp3Array.obj") ?: '';
            $array1 = json_decode($stringified1, true) ?: [];
            $stringified2 = file_get_contents($fileDir."/findArray.obj") ?: '';
            $array2 = json_decode($stringified2, true) ?: [];
            
            $object->file_dir = $fileDir;
            $object->mp3Array = $object->arrayDecode($array1);
            $object->findArray = $array2;
        }
        return $object;
    }
    
    private function arrayEncode($arr){
        $tmp = [];
        foreach($arr as $key => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                $tmp[$key] = $this->arrayEncode($val);
            }else if ($key == "data"){
                $tmp[$key] = base64_encode($val);
            }else{
            $tmp[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $tmp;
    }
    private function arrayDecode($arr){
        $tmp = [];
        foreach($arr as $key => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                $tmp[$key] = $this->arrayDecode($val);
            }else if ($key == "data"){
                $tmp[$key] = base64_decode($val);
            }else{
            $tmp[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $tmp;
    }

    public function setMp3(array $new_array): void {
        $this->mp3Array = $new_array;
        $stringified = json_encode($new_array);
        file_put_contents($this->file_dir."/mp3Array.obj", $stringified);
    }
    public function saveMp3(): void {
        $base64 = $this->arrayEncode($this->mp3Array);
        $stringified = json_encode($base64);
       file_put_contents($this->file_dir."/mp3Array.obj", $stringified);
    }
    public function setFind(array $new_array): void {
        $this->findArray = $new_array;
        $stringified = json_encode($new_array);
        file_put_contents($this->file_dir."/findArray.obj", $stringified);
    }
    public function saveFind(): void {
        $stringified = json_encode( $this->findArray);
        file_put_contents($this->file_dir."/findArray.obj", $stringified);
    }
```